# как завершить поток который запускает поток (QThread)?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qt5

У меня есть поток (связанный с кнопкой) который запускает два потока поочерёдно, открывает и закрывает их. И когда  я "отжимаю" кнопку, то у меня закрывается главный поток а дочерний всё равно работает (так и работает до закрытия программы ).

**Включение главного потока:**

```
void MainWindow::on_pB_Cickl_toggled(bool checked)
{
    qDebug() << "on_pB_Cickl_toggled: " << "Зашли";
    if(checked == true)
    {
        ui->pB_run_stypen->setEnabled(false);
        ui->pB_Statrt->setEnabled(false);
        ui->pB_Stop->setEnabled(false);

        thread_schet = new QThread(); 
        mythread_otpr_schet = new MyThread_otpr_Schet();
        connect(thread_schet,SIGNAL(started()),mythread_otpr_schet,SLOT(Start()));
        mythread_otpr_schet->moveToThread(thread_schet);
        thread_schet->start();
    }
    if(checked == false)
    {
        qDebug() << "checked == false : " << "Вышли " <<checked ;
        thread_schet->requestInterruption();
        thread_schet->quit();

        chista_per = false;
         ui->pB_run_stypen->setEnabled(true);
        ui->pB_Statrt->setEnabled(true);
        ui->pB_Stop->setEnabled(true);
     }
}
```

**Дочерний поток который запускает поочерёдно два потока:**

```
void MyThread_otpr_Schet::Start(){
    chista_per = false;
    pB_timers = new QTimer(this);
    connect(pB_timers,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(slotCickl_period()));
    pB_timers->start(3000);
}

void MyThread_otpr_Schet::slotCickl_period()
{
    qDebug() << "slotCickl_period: " << "тут";
    chista_per = !chista_per ; 

    if(chista_per == true)
    {
        if(D_Start == true)
        {
        thread_OTKL->requestInterruption();
        thread_OTKL->quit();
        }

        thread_VKL = new QThread(); 
        my_potok_vklych = new MyThr_otpr_Sch_vkl();
        connect(thread_VKL,SIGNAL(started()),my_potok_vklych,SLOT(Start()));
        my_potok_vklych->moveToThread(thread_VKL);
        thread_VKL->start();

        D_Start = true;
    }
    if(chista_per == false)
    {
        if(D_Start == true)
        {
        thread_VKL->requestInterruption();
        thread_VKL->quit();
        }

        thread_OTKL = new QThread(); 
        my_potok_otklych = new MyThr_otpr_Sch_otkl();
        connect(thread_OTKL,SIGNAL(started()),my_potok_otklych,SLOT(Start()));
        my_potok_otklych->moveToThread(thread_OTKL);
        thread_OTKL->start();

        D_Start = true;
    }
}
```

И вот проблема - дочерний поток закрывается а дочки дочернего нет (точнее один из них).

*Многопоточность реализую через QThread.*

---

Я как понимаю не вызвано " закрытие " потока. Но я так и не понял и не нашёл в документации сигнал закрытия потока.

Comment: Вы уверены? Дочерние потоки (thread_OTKL, thread_VKL) должны закрываться почти сразу после выполнения `thread_VKL->start();`, поскольку никакой процедуры, которая бы выполнялась в этом потоке не установлено, цикла обработки сообщений тоже нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**В общем добавил слот:**

```
void MyThread_otpr_Schet::Stop()
{
    pB_timers->stop();
    if(chista_per == true)
    {
        thread_VKL->requestInterruption();
        thread_VKL->quit();
    }
    if(chista_per == false)
    {
        thread_OTKL->requestInterruption();
        thread_OTKL->quit();
    }
}
```

**И изменил место запуска:**

```
void MainWindow::on_pB_Cickl_toggled(bool checked)
{
    qDebug() << "on_pB_Cickl_toggled: " << "Зашли";
    if(checked == true)
    {
        ui->pB_run_stypen->setEnabled(false);
        ui->pB_Statrt->setEnabled(false);
        ui->pB_Stop->setEnabled(false);

        thread_schet = new QThread(); 
        mythread_otpr_schet = new MyThread_otpr_Schet();
        connect(thread_schet,SIGNAL(started()),mythread_otpr_schet,SLOT(Start()));
        mythread_otpr_schet->moveToThread(thread_schet);
        thread_schet->start();
    }
    if(checked == false)
    {
         //connect(thread_schet,SIGNAL(signal_schet()),mythread_otpr_schet,SLOT(Stop())); //не раб вариант (разваливает программу)
        //signal_schet();

        qDebug() << "checked == false : " << "Вышли " <<checked ;
        thread_schet->requestInterruption();
        connect(thread_schet,SIGNAL(finished()),mythread_otpr_schet,SLOT(Stop())); // вот добавил
        thread_schet->quit();

        chista_per = false;
        ui->pB_run_stypen->setEnabled(true);
        ui->pB_Statrt->setEnabled(true);
        ui->pB_Stop->setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Заработало :3